# Draw a line between to "Max/Min" Points

Tags: vb.net, gdi+

Well, I'm back with another brain buster :)

I need to draw a line between 2 shots that are the max spread.

I am using the below code, but it draws the lines between the rectangle corners.  I know this is wrong, but not sure how to find the points using this code.

I updated the code very long hand (so my brain can wrap around it).

Basically one of the "L" variables will test out to be the longest.  I then need to grab the corresponding points to that "L" variable.

```
 Private Sub DrawMaxCTCLine(g As Graphics)
            Dim minx, miny, maxx, maxy As Integer
    Dim P1, P2, P3, P4 As Point
    Dim L1, L2, L3, L4, L5, L6 As Decimal

    maxx = shotList.Max(Function(point) point.X)
    maxy = shotList.Max(Function(point) point.Y)
    minx = shotList.Min(Function(point) point.X)
    miny = shotList.Min(Function(point) point.Y)

    P1 = shotList.Find(Function(point) point.X = maxx)
    P2 = shotList.Find(Function(point) point.Y = maxy)
    P3 = shotList.Find(Function(point) point.X = minx)
    P4 = shotList.Find(Function(point) point.Y = miny)

    L1 = Math.Sqrt((P1.X - P2.X) ^ 2 + (P1.Y - P2.Y) ^ 2)
    L2 = Math.Sqrt((P1.X - P3.X) ^ 2 + (P1.Y - P3.Y) ^ 2)
    L3 = Math.Sqrt((P1.X - P4.X) ^ 2 + (P1.Y - P4.Y) ^ 2)
    L4 = Math.Sqrt((P2.X - P3.X) ^ 2 + (P2.Y - P3.Y) ^ 2)
    L5 = Math.Sqrt((P2.X - P4.X) ^ 2 + (P2.Y - P4.Y) ^ 2)
    L6 = Math.Sqrt((P3.X - P4.X) ^ 2 + (P3.Y - P4.Y) ^ 2)
```

here is a better image of the line i am talking about (highlighted)

[image]

Here is an image when only 2 shots are shown (which works)
[image]

Here is an image when 3 or more shots are shown (which doesn't work work)
Note the line is drawn to the upper left corner and not the shot
[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the dashed white line or the dashed red line?  It's not clear what should be happening from your images.  Also, you are leaking GDI objects.  You need to dispose of your `Pen` when you are done with it.

Comment: Dashed white line, sorry, I can see how that is not clear.  Thanks for catching the leaking as well.  Was not paying attention.

Comment: Where should the dashed white line be drawn from and to?  I think the problem is that `minx` and `miny` don't belong to the same points.  `minx` seems to belong to shot 1 while `miny` belongs to shot 3

Comment: I'm working the code, but my thoughts are getting 4 points that have minX, minY, maxX, maxY. Find the distance between each of those points and grabbing the max distance.  Assuming this is the correct approach, I now have to figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got it to work, the long way.  Open to anything that is more concise.

```
  Private Sub DrawMaxCTCLine(g As Graphics)
    Dim minx, miny, maxx, maxy As Integer
    Dim P1, P2, P3, P4 As Point
    Dim L1, L2, L3, L4, L5, L6 As Decimal
    Dim maxSpread As Decimal = 0

    maxx = shotList.Max(Function(point) point.X)
    maxy = shotList.Max(Function(point) point.Y)
    minx = shotList.Min(Function(point) point.X)
    miny = shotList.Min(Function(point) point.Y)

    P1 = shotList.Find(Function(point) point.X = maxx)
    P2 = shotList.Find(Function(point) point.Y = maxy)
    P3 = shotList.Find(Function(point) point.X = minx)
    P4 = shotList.Find(Function(point) point.Y = miny)

    L1 = Math.Sqrt((P1.X - P2.X) ^ 2 + (P1.Y - P2.Y) ^ 2)
    L2 = Math.Sqrt((P1.X - P3.X) ^ 2 + (P1.Y - P3.Y) ^ 2)
    L3 = Math.Sqrt((P1.X - P4.X) ^ 2 + (P1.Y - P4.Y) ^ 2)
    L4 = Math.Sqrt((P2.X - P3.X) ^ 2 + (P2.Y - P3.Y) ^ 2)
    L5 = Math.Sqrt((P2.X - P4.X) ^ 2 + (P2.Y - P4.Y) ^ 2)
    L6 = Math.Sqrt((P3.X - P4.X) ^ 2 + (P3.Y - P4.Y) ^ 2)

    Dim lList As New List(Of Decimal)
    lList.Add(L1)
    lList.Add(L2)
    lList.Add(L3)
    lList.Add(L4)
    lList.Add(L5)
    lList.Add(L6)

    maxSpread = lList.Max()

    Dim pn As New Pen(My.Settings.Max_Spread_Line, 1)
    Dim Dash As Single() = {2, 5, 2, 5}

    pn.DashPattern = Dash

    Select Case maxSpread
        Case L1
            g.DrawLine(pn, P1, P2)
        Case L2
            g.DrawLine(pn, P1, P3)
        Case L3
            g.DrawLine(pn, P1, P4)
        Case L4
            g.DrawLine(pn, P2, P3)
        Case L5
            g.DrawLine(pn, P2, P4)
        Case L6
            g.DrawLine(pn, P3, P4)
    End Select

    pn.Dispose()
    lList.Clear()

    Console.WriteLine("P1" & P1.ToString & vbCrLf & "P2" & P2.ToString & vbCrLf & "P3" & P3.ToString & vbCrLf & "P4" & P4.ToString)
    Console.WriteLine(L1.ToString & vbCrLf & L2.ToString & vbCrLf & L3.ToString & vbCrLf & L4.ToString & vbCrLf & L5.ToString & vbCrLf & L6.ToString)
    Console.WriteLine(maxSpread)

End Sub
```